# Disable-TlsCipherSuite : Exception from HRESULT: 0xD0000225

Tags: powershell, comexception

When I disable the cipher `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384` in powershell of windows server,
I got this error message

```
Disable-TlsCipherSuite : Exception from HRESULT: 0xD0000225
At line:1 char:1
+ Disable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Disable-TlsCipherSuite], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Exception from HRESULT: 0xD0000225,Microsoft.WindowsAuthenticationProtocols.Commands.RemoveTlsCipherSuiteCommand
```

What does the error mean and how to fix it?
Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Interesting. HRESULT is interpreted as 0xD (severe failure, NT status bit set) and the error is 0x0225 which is stated to be [ERROR_INSTRUCTION_MISALIGNMENT (0x225)] aka some code is not properly aligned in memory. Either you've discovered a bug in cryptography which is masked because the ciphersuite affected is not used in favor of AES256/SHA384, or there is some internal protection at work, like if disabling this ciphersuite would seriously break say Microsoft signature verification or similar Windows-important process.

Comment: Anyone? Im getting same error with this Disable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error simply indicate the cipher is already disabled....

try `Enable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384`
and `Disable-TlsCipherSuite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384`
no error should appear

Comment: My question is why Get-TlsCipherSuite still returns it if it's disabled

Comment: I have the same question

Comment: Run the Powershell as administrator and try it.

Comment: @IgorPashchuk What if you first enable the Group Policy variable for the cipher suite order? If it's disabled, I don't think changes will be applied—the default order and _all available ciphers_ will be used. Its hierarchy is: Local Computer Policy › Administrative Template › Network › SSL Configuration Settings › SSL Cipher Suite Order

Comment: It returns if it is disabled because the cipher suite may be *installed* but not *in use*. I do think the Powershell cmdlet for this should simply return an informative message like "Suite disabled" rather than the cryptic 0xD0000225.

Answer (score 3):

Run the Powershell as administrator and try it

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The same error 0x0000225 occurred when trying to disable some cipher suites. It turned out that the cipher suites were explicitly specified in the Local Computer policy. Computer Configuration >> Administrative Templates >> Network >> SSL Configuration Settings >> SSL cipher suite order. Here you need to specify the required cipher suites, separated by commas.  After this request  Get-TlsCipherSuite | ft name  produced the required result.